# “it's truly vital that he or she becomes/become familiar with the reasons”?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, subjunctive-mood, mandative-subjunctive

Please have a look at the sentence below:

> Before one votes on the propositions, it's truly vital that he or she becomes familiar with the reasons for voting both for the proposition and against the proposition.*

My book says, *become familiar… proposal*. That is, *becomes* should be *become*. Is there a grammatical difference? Is one more correct than the other?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up _proposal_ and _proposition_. Is this accidental, or do you actually mean to ask something about that? As for the use of the _subjunctive_, I'm afraid that is general reference on this site. A question about that would fit better on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: He did: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51463/grammar-proposals

Comment: The choice between "become" and "becomes" is here a choice between subjunctive and indicative moods, respectively. Either is acceptable, but the subjunctive is more formal. By the way, if you start by using the pronoun "one" for a single person of indeterminate sex, you really should stick with it, though it tends to sound stuffy, that is, painfully formal. At that level of formality the contraction would be spelled out: "Before one votes on the propositions, it is vital that one become familiar with the reasons for voting either for or against each."

Comment: My problem is which one is correct.

Comment: As I said, either is acceptable, but the subjunctive, "become," is more formal.

Comment: So please make an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of "votes" and the subject of "becomes familiar" refer to the same person in the example:

> Before one votes on the propositions, it's truly vital that he or she becomes familiar with the reasons for voting both for the proposition and against the proposition.

So it would be peculiar to have one subject be singular and the other plural.  But you could make both plural, I suppose:

> Before people vote on the propositions, it's truly vital that they become familiar with the reasons for voting both for the proposition and against the proposition.